# Use Batch file to Run exe and Output Results to Text

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a program that runs from the cmd prompt that will run continuously as it is outputting text.  I can have it output the text to a text file by adding `> path\filename.ext` to the end.  I want to write a batch file that will write to a text file.  It should timestamp the beginning, run for 30 seconds, then timestamp at the end.  This is what I have:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:/ " %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a:%%b %%c)
set mytime=%mytime: =% 
echo %mydate%_%mytime% > path\results.txt
start runfile.exe --option=alpha path/data.ext >> path\results.txt
timeout /t 30
taskkill /im runfile.exe /f
echo %mydate%_%mytime% >> path\results.txt
```

There are 2 problems with this, 1) it is not outputting runfile.exe to my text file, and 2) it is not terminating runfile.exe after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

1) In your `start runfile.xe parms` line, try to use `start "" runfile.exe parms`

2) When you start runfile.exe, what is the image name? When you start task manager, is it still called "runfile.exe" or does it change to something else?

I have a program that uses a launcher. The launcher is called "runme.exe" (this is just an example) which in turn preps other programs for a program called "programname.exe" If I wanted to kill that task, I would have to kill "programname.exe" as that is the program that remains in memory after "runme.exe" finishes executing. Check and see if your program does something similar.

Hope this helps.